# iOS array copy, how to release?

Tags: ios, memory-management

What is the proper way to release an array that you created with copy? I have a function createDoc that takes an NSMutableArray as an argument. I get a memory leak because I believe copy allocates memory.

```
doc = [getDoc createDoc: [[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 5)] copy] ];
```

Comment: Why are you creating a copy of the array? That's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
doc = [getDoc createDoc: [[[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 5)] copy] autorelease]];
```

or even better this

```
NSArray *subArray = [[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 5)] copy]];
doc = [getDoc createDoc:subArray];
[subArray release];
```

Answer (score 0):

you would release the copy. that's all.

```
NSArray * copy = [[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 5)] copy];
doc = [getDoc createDoc:copy];
[copy release];
```

but - what you want is a mutable copy, if that's what the parameter requires:

```
NSMutableArray * copy = [[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 5)] mutableCopy];
  ^^^^^^^                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
doc = [getDoc createDoc:copy];
[copy release];
```

even better in most cases, would be to declare the parameter as an array, than have the object `getDoc` create its `mutableCopy`.